# How to add new members in Group using Firebase

Tags: javascript, swift, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing the app which has grouping function.
Now I have the problem about adding new member in group.

Like Slack, in group creating onboarding flow user can decide group name and add members which don't use the app yet.
As adding members function, I want to use inviting mail link using firebase dynamic links.

Data structure　is below

```
User
 - id
 - name
 - email

Group
  - id
  - groupName
  - members[]
```

Group's members array has user id.
But when someone creates new group, it is possible that new users don't register the app yet.
So they don't have user id property in the app.

How do I fix this problem?
When someone creates new group, should I develop sign up functions new user using Firebase auth?　This means then new member has automatically user id, and adding those to members property.
Or should group member array have mail address instead of user id.

Please tell me. I'm happy with Swift or JavaScript you will teach me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### UPDATE

After reading your comment I would propose another approach.

When the Group creator user adds users to a group, if a user does not already exists you could, from the front-end, call a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) (CF) that creates a temporary Firestore document in a specific collection. The ID of this document will be the (future) userId.

Then, still in this same Cloud Function, you send an email to the email address (you need to generate yourself the email, for example with the email extension) with a link containing the userId as query string value.

Example of code for this first CF:

```
exports.provisionNewAccount = functions
    .https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

        try {

            // You can check that the caller is authenticated
            // if (context.auth.uid) {execute the rest of the code} else {throw an error} 

            // New user email
            const userEmail = data.email;

            // Generate the new user docID
            const fakeDocRef = admin.firestore().collection('_').doc();
            const requestId = fakeDocRef.id;

            // Create the doc in a specific collection
            await admin.firestore().collection('usersCreationRequests').doc(requestId).set({ email: userEmail, treated: false });

            // Generate the link to include in the email
            const linkURL = 'https://your.app/register.html?requestId=' + requestId
            
            // Send the email by creating a doc in the Extension collection
            await db
                .collection("emails")
                .add({
                    to: userEmail,
                    message: {
                        subject: "....",
                        html: `<a href="${linkURL}">Click to create your account</a>`  // adapt the html to add some text
                    },
                });
                
                return {result: 'OK'}

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', JSON.stringify(error));
        }

    });
```

You call it as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function), by passing the future user's email.

When the email recipient clicks on the link, you open a specific page of your web app that shows a set of fields for the future user to enter his password, display name etc. Then on clicking on a sign-in button in this page you call a Callable Cloud Function passing it the Firestore document ID plus the field values (you get the document ID from the query string).

As shown below, this Cloud Function creates the user in the Authentication service (using the Admin SDK) and flag the Firestore document as treated. Upon getting back the Cloud Function result in the web app you authenticate the user (you have his email and password, since he/she entered it in the form).

```
exports.createNewAccount = functions
    .https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

        try {

            const userEmail = data.email;
            const userId = data.userId;
            const userPassword = data.password;
            const userDisplayName = data.displayName;

            // Fetch the user doc created in the first CF
            const snapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('usersCreationRequests').doc(userId).get();

            const treated = snapshot.get('treated');
            const email = snapshot.get('email');

            if (!treated && userEmail === email) {

                const createUserPayload = {
                    email,
                    emailVerified: false,
                    password: userPassword,
                    displayName: userDisplayName
                };

                const userRecord = await admin.auth().createUser(createUserPayload);

                return { result: 'OK' }

            } else {

                return { result: 'User already created' }

            }


        } catch (error) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', JSON.stringify(error));
        }

    });
```

---

I’m actually using this exact approach for a B2B collaborative web app in which users can invite new users by email.

---

#### INITIAL ANSWER

(Totally different from the update)

> So they don't have user id property in the app… How do I fix this
> problem? When someone creates new group, should I develop sign up
> functions new user using Firebase auth?

You can use the [Anonymous Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth) mode, it exactly corresponds to your needs:

> You can use Firebase Authentication to create and use temporary
> anonymous accounts to authenticate with Firebase. These temporary
> anonymous accounts can be used to allow users who haven't yet signed
> up to your app to work with data protected by security rules. If an
> anonymous user decides to sign up to your app, you can link their
> sign-in credentials to the anonymous account so that they can continue
> to work with their protected data in future sessions.

When signing-in with Anonymous Authentication a userId (`uid`) will be created and later you will be able to convert an anonymous account to a permanent account

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248370/discussion-on-answer-by-renaud-tarnec-how-to-add-new-members-in-group-using-fire).

Comment: Hi, Renaud. I got one question about the function you taught me.
It creates only one user. So I mean if owner wants to add more than one people,
Should I call  the cloud function the same times using `for`?

Comment: Hi Shun, yes you can use a loop, but you then need to use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), see the many answers I gave on this subject: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a3371862%20Promise.all

Comment: Hi, Renaud. Thank you for supporting me. So you mean I can also use for loop, and I also should use `Promise.all` . When I read the some materials you taught me, You use like this ```Array.forEach((doc) => {const starsRef = ref(storage, `images/${doc.id}/poster.png`);
  promises.push(getDownloadURL(starsRef));
});
const urlsArray = await Promise.all(promises);
```
why do you use promise.all in  forEach.? I think it is enough in forEach each item should just call `https.onCall` . Why do you recommend that? Thank you.

Comment: We don't use `Promise.all` **in** `forEach`. In the `forEach` block we populate an array of Promises that we later pass to `Promise.all()`. We need to do that because we want to execute a **unknown variable number** of calls to the **asynchronous** `getDownloadURL()` method **in parallel**. Reading the Promise.all doc will give you more details.

Comment: Hi, Renaud! Thank you for quick response.  I will learn more based on what you advised me. Later if I don't know the detail, plz help me again. I appreciate you.

Comment: Hi, Renaud. Thank you for the tips. I did success in `provisionNewAccount` CF. And I got success sending emails and getting those. 
Now Im thinking about `createNewAccount` and its frontend. In its frontend should I make the email form? I think user don’t need input that. So should I just display your email?  In `createNewAccount` you showed me, data.email is used as like token. So should I make its email form? Please teach me your opinion. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Shun, not sure to understand your question. You are not obliged to make the email field editable or even visible since you can know it from the userID.

Comment: Hi, Renaud. I have one more question now.
Now I’m developing to add some Auth provider login like Google Login, Apple Login.
When I invite new users in email & password login, they will sign up using Cloud function to use the requestId I sent them.
But in Auth provider login, how do I control the new uid OAuthProvider issues and connect it to requestId? 
When I use Auth provider login, it creates their accounts and their uid base on `OAuthProvider.credential` in Frontend. I can’t create  their accounts and uid like using email login’s  `requestId` I sent user. 
Plz teach me. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @ShunTakahashi, I recommend asking a new question.

Comment: Hi, Renaud. I created the one. Plz answer it.
[how to connect the invited users email and provider login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74755607/how-to-connect-the-invited-users-email-and-provider-login-by-using-firebase)
Thank you.

Comment: Hi Renaud. I really want your help.  Sorry I don't know how to mention you in new question.
 The app already know about `requestId` in frontend when the invited user sign up. So once the invited user’s account are created by using Provider login like Apple sign in and Google login, using another Cloud functions should I change `requestId` in Group’s members to the provider account’s uid?  I need your help so much. Please tell me your good advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I always use userId to achive this kind of feature, you can use anonymous authentication to get userId after user click invite link, Then if needed unlock more feature with furter authentication(add more provider).

If you only using mail address without authentication, It's hard to write rules for prevent user access unwanted data, Like anyone knew your email are able to access your account.

Comment: Hi, flutroid. Thank you for supporting me. Do you mean when group owner clicks invitation link, each invited users are registered by using anonymous authentication, right?  Ex) I invite abc@exaple.com, def@exaple.com, then each new users are registered by anonymous authentication.  But I have one question. When I make reference to firebase docs, that is method below `Auth.auth().signInAnonymously { authResult, error in }`. I think this method is not linked with invited users's mail address.  So how do I dev those using their mail address and linking them. Please teach me. Thank you.